# Why automated suggestion isn't showing up

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have created a stored procedure in the New Query window. I made sure that my database for the new procedure matches the database for which I created the stored procedure.

I executed the creation of the stored procedure successfully. I then refreshed the window structure and it shows the new created stored procedure (in this case, spGetEmployeesByGenderAndSalary

[image: spGetEmployeesByGenderAndSalary]

but when I try to run it in the query window, it doesn't show up in the suggested features.

[image: not_spGetEmployeesByGenderAndSalary]

Not to say it doesn't acknowledge it's existence. If I simply type out

`EXEC spGetEmployeesByGenderAndSalary` it runs fine

I just don't understand why it doesn't show up in the automated suggestions box.

*Update*- apparently it appears if I close out SSMS entirely and reboot it, now it shows up fine. Is it always like this, though? Is it some kind of glitch? Anyone else had this issue?

Also, what's this feature called? Intellisense?

Comment: I think Intellisense cache (used for SP names etc) is different from normal display in menus etc. I add a button to my toolbar called 'Refresh Local Cache'. It's also in the Edit -> Intellisense menu, and you can use CTRL-SHIFT-R. To add it to a toolbar, 'add or remove buttons' from the toolbar, select 'customise', then 'add command' and it's in the 'Edit' commands.

Comment: very good answer. **((selects it as defacto best))**